# What are some pros and cons of a cuboid soda can?

Tags: help, project

What is some pros and cons of a rectangular cuboid? I only have a few advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are aluminium soda cans typically round instead of square?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91445/why-are-aluminium-soda-cans-typically-round-instead-of-square)

Answer (score 2):

https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/4x3m4m/the-brilliant-design-of-the-soda-can-explained

> As YouTube's "Engineerguy" Bill Hammack explains, the can's brilliant design is a cylinder because it contains the best parts of a sphere (its surface area) with a cuboid-shaped design that makes the can sturdy and stackable.